# Android ROM and Raspberry PI 3 plus NFC

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-room, android-things

We are working with Android Things on Raspberry pi 3, everything works great, recently we got an NXP board called OM5578/PN7150, basically to use NFC efficiently.

Through NXP guide (AN11690 NXPNCI Android Porting Guidelines) I need:

- Add the drive in the Kernel
- Customize the AOSP (Android Open Source Project)

I would like to know:

Which version of the **kernel** is best for recompiling by **adding the drive** with **Raspberry pi 3** support

Which version of AOSP is recommended for Raspberry pi 3 **in kiosk mode** (similar to Android Things).

Another board is not an option.

Thanks.

Comment: Android Things is not open sourced yet.

Comment: @Onik i know that, look the question, i mention the AOSP

Answer (score 2):

- Android Things only allows User-Space Drivers, loading additional kernel modules isn't permitted. Unfortunately there is currently no User-Space driver types that would be suitable for NFC: https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/drivers/index.html
- Since your NFC device seems to be I2C based, it would be possible to access it via Android Things PIO API: https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/i2c.html. You could basically port an Arduino example. This is only a valid approach if the app that you intend to run is your own (because if not, the app would try to access the NFC module via the normal Android API instead of your own one).
- If you want to follow the NXP porting guidelines using the ASOP, start with a fork that was already adapted for the RPi, like this one: https://github.com/lineage-rpi.
- The kiosk mode is a secondary problem which you should be able to solve with most more recent android versions.