# Android Things and NFC

Tags: nfc, android-things

I'm running Android Things on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I want to read NFC Tags, is it possible to do this? I've got like zero hardware knowledge about this stuff. All I know is how to write the necessary code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48792523/3290339

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Raspberry Pi (or the other Dev kit) does not have NFC hardware. If you want to read NFC tags you need to get some hardware.

In addition to that, there is not user space driver for NFC, so you'd need to read it using a driver.

I only know of 2 chips that are sort of supported, both drivers are very limited. In fact, the simplest way to get them to work is to plug then into an Arduino and then communicate with the Arduino either using UART or I2C.

The best supported chip is RC-522. It reads mifare, but not sure how many other formats. You have a driver ported from arduino here: http://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522 
One of the important limitations is that it does not support card emulation.

Comment: Do you by chance know which chips are sort of supported? Connecting an Arduino would make it to expensive..

Comment: You have this one: RC-522 it reads mifare, but not sure how many other formats, it's the best supported one https://github.com/Galarzaa90/android-things-rc522 it does not support card emulation.

Comment: I just added the previous comment into the answer to make it easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with the ACR122U running over USB. It supports Mifare.

Comment: Did you have to use any user space driver and did it work with a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: It worked really well with Raspberry Pi, and I just had to install a PCSC driver. It was quite simple. There are many good guides, and I'd like to link a comprehensive resource, but I cannot remember which I used.